# Force MariaDB Galera to only create InnoDB tables

Tags: mariadb, galera

I successfully run a cluster of 3 DB servers using MariaDB Galera 10.0.16. This setup handels a couple of web apps we have created, plus a dozen medium traffic Joomla websites.

My problem is that Galera doesn't like MyISAM. Pretty often, when a plugin or component in Joomla gets installed, it sets the MySQL engine in its install.sql like so:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

When that happens, a simple Joomla component installation can (and has) break the replication.

Is there a way that I can *force* the server to ignore the ENGINE setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percona XtraDB Cluster has this feature already (enforce_storage_engine) and for MariaDB there is a pending feature request reported by me to Colin...

https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-6858

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wasn't aware that Percona offers that, so I guess that the question now is if this is important enough for us to migrate to Percona.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. People [tend to want that when using NDB cluster and Galera](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?25,521792,521868).

The right answer is that you should report the plugin creators to create the tables with no engine definition, so you can set it with "default_engine" option. While on other cases you could disable the engine and force the engine substitution with the default one, that is not a good practice, it is [discouraged on the latest versions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) and [impossible with MyISAM](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/disabling-storage-engines/).

The truth is that once the developer writes `ENGINE=X`, it is forcing the creation of the engine, as written. The only way to accomplish that is by rewriting the query on-the-fly. That is available in MySQL 5.7 (not yet GA), [with several plugins](http://mysqlserverteam.com/the-query-rewrite-plugins/). **The only way I can think of doing it now is with a SQL proxy like [ProxySQL](https://github.com/renecannao/proxysql) or [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-proxy/en/)**. Please note that some of those are [infamous for bad performance](http://www.proxysql.com/2013/10/simple-benchmark-on-mysql-proxy-vs.html), so you may want to enable it only on plugin activation/disabling.

There is obviously another option: download the MariaDB Cluster sources, disable MyISAM on the `CREATE TABLE` Syntax, and compile!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess from manually compiling MariaDB each time there is an update it would be easier to migrate to Percona or have our own forks of the plugins we usually use.